# How do I get ngx-charts tooltip templates working?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

We have an Angular application using ngx-charts to display a line-chart. The chart mostly works fine - but I cannot get any tooltips to display using any of the template examples that I've found thus far.

Below is my chart HTML - I currently have string constant values (not even dynamic data values from the data set) just to see if I can get ANYTHING to display - and so far nothing! Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? (I'm that figuring once I get the static strings working, displaying dynamic data will then be possible.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
    [legend]="true"
    [legendPosition]="'bottom'"
    [legendTitle]="''"
    [xAxis]="true"
    [xAxisLabel]="'Date'"
    [showXAxisLabel]="true"
    [yAxis]="true"
    [yAxisLabel]="'Number of Institutions'"
    [showYAxisLabel]="true"
    [results]="chartData"
    [xAxisTickFormatting]="xAxisTickFormatting"
>
    <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
        <div class="chart-tooltip">
            <span>Testing</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #seriesTooltipTemplate let-model="model">
        <div class="chart-tooltip">
            testing
            <div *ngFor="let tooltipItem of model">
                {{ 'test' }}
            </div>
        </div>
   </ng-template>
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Comment: You're missing the `tooltipTemplate` input on `<ngx-charts-line-chart/>`

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify or provide a brief example? Thanks!